# php: "Dynamic Class Instantiation" what is the purpose of this pattern\snippet

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, factory, prototypal-inheritance

I reading [the following article](http://ralphschindler.com/2012/03/09/php-constructor-best-practices-and-the-prototype-pattern) and got very confused on the "Dynamic Class Instantiation" part. Specifically this code snippet:

```
$obj = new $className();
if (!$obj instanceof SomeBaseType) {
    throw new \InvalidTypeException();
}
```

I don't understand what this is actually doing for you. If its not an instance of a base class it errors out. How is that helpful? It doesn't get an instance of the correct type, or perform a different action based on the current type, it just throws an exception. I'm having trouble conceptualizing the purpose of this code and the article didn't really clear it up for me.

---------Complete section from the article----------

"Dynamic Class Instantiation

Generally speaking, the following code, while legal, should be used very seldom, and only when other possible instantiation patterns have been exhausted:

```
$obj = new $className();
if (!$obj instanceof SomeBaseType) {
    throw new \InvalidTypeException();
}
```

Why is this a bad pattern? First, it makes the assumption up front that the constructor signature is free from any required parameters. While this is good for object types that are already known to this factory, it might not always be true of a consumers subtype of the base object in question. This patten should never be used on objects that have dependencies, or in situations where it is conceivable that a subtype might have dependencies because this takes away the possibility for a subtype to practice constructor injection.

Another problem is that instead of managing an object, or a list of objects, you are now managing a class name, or list of class names in addition to an object or list of objects. Instead, one could simply manage the objects.

If, on the other hand, you know this particular object type is no more than a value object (or similar), with no chance of it needing dependencies in subtypes, you can then cautiously use this instantiation pattern."

Comment: This is hack. Used by people who do not understand namespacing and factories.

Comment: OK, I still don't understand it though.